# lightning :navigation or :workspaceapi? What's my best option?

Tags: navigation, workspaceapi

I see the Lightning docs demonstrate using `<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>`
 with workspaceAPI here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_open_pagereference.htm

but show `<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>` with the example here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation

Anyone know which is best here?

Comment: can you give more explanation for your use case?

Comment: Opening console tabs using the pagereference types available to the workspaceapi as seen in the two different doc pages.

Comment: I have a related question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265477/open-lightning-console-tab-for-edit-and-view-all-at-once