# In Lightning: Record Edit modal box is not opening for first time [using $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-console

I've created a lightning component in which a Case record will get create automatically(using force:recordData) from account and contact. Once the record gets created at the backend I need to redirect the page to newly created case and at the same time need to open edit pop up for same record.[image: ths is what i need]
Actually I'm using this component in the lightning service console so facing 2 problems:
1.  for the first time, on selection of case record type from account or contact a Case record is getting created but edit window is not opening.  And if I select the record type again from different account or contact record edit window will popup. 
2. As I'm using service console if I select the record type from account or contact case will get create and redirect to new tab in console. But trying to reset the component or value or want to refresh the particular account . or contact tab in the console so that I can select another record type and works the same way.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post your code? If you are using service console, then use workspace api to navigate to records.

Comment: @NagendraSingh I've tried the workspace api  also and its redirecting the new tab but edit popup of same record is not working in that case.

Comment: try combining the two like this : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/265683/45062

Open it via workspace api and use Navigationapi to trigger the record mode.

Comment: only tab is opening but edit popup is not coming.

Comment: Did you add navigator api? What is the error?

Comment: Yes
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navigator"/>

Comment: I've added both the APIs and there is no error.

Comment: @NagendraSingh now I'm using  $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL"); and my code is working. Problem is whenever the page loads and i select the case record type for the first time  it will not popup the edit window. But if i select for next time for n number without refreshing the whole page it will open the edit popup always. Only for first time it is not working. Can you please help in this case?

Comment: The code below works fine. Are you using `<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>` , also your bundle version should be more than 43 for this to work.

Comment: If thats still not working then try modified version of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use navigation api in combination with your workspace api.

Like this:

```
handleRecordTypeSelection: function (component, event, helper) {
    var recordTypeName = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    component.set("v.caseField.RecordTypeId", recordTypeName);
    component.find("caseRecordCreator").saveRecord(function (saveResult) {
        if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
            var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
            workspaceAPI.openTab({
                recordId: saveResult.recordId, 
                focus: true
            }).then(function() {
                navigatorApi.navigate({
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: saveResult.recordId,
                        actionName: 'edit'
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Or Like this ;

```
workspaceAPI.openTab({
    recordId:  v,
    focus: true
 }).then(function() {
    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
        "recordId": v
    });
    editRecordEvent.fire();
 })
```

Comment: thanks, it worked.